# Got Double Badges for this election

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, election

I have been awarded the Caucus and Constituent badges multiple times very shortly after each other.
Is this a bug or am i missing something?

[image: Listy]

Caucus

[image: Caucus]

Constituent

[image: Constituent]

Comment: one badge is for this season and another one is for previous one, check the link on the badge

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The badges  Constituent and Caucus are recently added to the site.  Visit the link https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1974/constituent?userid=310741 , you will find a page like below image,

[image]

Also this link https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1973/caucus?userid=310741 you will find a page like below image,

[image]

when you click on that red marked circle, it will take you to the election page where you voted. So here it shows that you have voted in this election and in the previous to previous election too.

This is the reason so have been awarded these badges 2 times.

Comment: Ah! So that is it... I might not be so confused had they bothered to include the year in the date.

Comment: @Josefvz the year is 2012 in both cases; you received the badges simultaneously (because the badge was only just created, but still gets awarded retroactively).

Answer (score 5):

The badges have only recently been added and they were back dated to include previous elections.

So you will have received the badges for past elections and the current election at the same time when the badges were introduced.

You can access the specific election clicking the link in your notification tab :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question: [Got Constituent badge thrice, is this right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140064)

I have a feeling that StackOverflow didn't get this right with awarding the badge multiple times. Voting is a privilege and not a strain. In a known direct democracy in central Europe people aren't also awarded for voting.

Therefore I posit that **one** award is enough if StackOverflow must award voting at all.

I just feel a bit embarrassed with so many Caucus and Constituent badges.