# Got Constituent badge thrice, is this right?

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Got Double Badges for this election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137237/got-double-badges-for-this-election)

Last month I received the Constituent silver badge thrice and I feel a little bit embarrassed.

Maybe there's a bug in awarding this badge? One should be enough. Or did I misunderstand the Constituent badge?

```
nalply earned this badge 3 times

jun 19 at 18:02 for an election
jun 8 at 23:13 for an election
jun 8 at 23:13 for an election
```

Comment: `Voted for a candidate in the final phase of an election. This badge can be awarded multiple times.` Seems like you voted either for three candidates or in three elections.

Comment: @UristMcBobby - you get one badge per election (assuming you vote of course)

Comment: Yes, it is right, check my [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137239/173001)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate. I couldn't find it.

Comment: Vote early, vote often!

Comment: Added an answer to the duplicate because I feel voting is a privilege, not a strain and does not need badges: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140069/139600